# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android

この前からこのバグがどうしても取れません。

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.pke.liveplusplus/com.pke.liveplusplus.activity.MainActivity}:
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/back.png
from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f020000
```

こんなエラーになります。

いろいろ検索してみましてproject clean からの再ビルドしても解消せず。
R.Javaの削除後自動生成し再ビルドも解消せず。

ですがdrawableのリソースはあります。
レイアウトでもちゃんと表示はしているのですが、、、

今回の事例はEclipseからAndroidStudio移行中におこりました。
方法としましてEclipseソースをAndroidStudioに1クラスずつコピペして行っています。

drawableFileはディレクトリごとコピーしました。

環境は
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 17

です。

どうかいい提案お願いします。

Comment: 問題が発生している箇所について、可能な範囲でコードの公開を行っていただけますか？問題の解決ができるかもしれません。

Comment: Android Studio  は Eclipse の Android プロジェクトを簡単に import できるはずですが、その方法で移行が可能だとして、その方法でもこの例外が発生するんでしょうか？